# .htaccess rewrite all subdomains to root

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This may be asked somewhere else but can't really find an answer to this one.

I want to redirect all the subdomains (*.domain.com) to the root (i.e. domain.com) using an htaccess. So in short:

```
test.domain.com -> domain.com
asdasdasd.domain.com -> domain.com
etc.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, it should work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/
```